# Why does ranger predict give different numbers when re-applied to training data?

Tags: r, random-forest, r-ranger

I am very new to machine learning. I am trying to explore fitting random forests with the ranger library in R. My dependent variable is continuous - so it would be a regression tree (and not just classification). Upon trying out the functions, I have noticed that there seems to be a discrepancy between ranger and predict ranger. The following lines result in **different predictions** in `results` and `results_alternative`:

```
rf_reg <- ranger(formula = y ~ ., data = training_df)

results <- rf_reg$predictions
results_alterantive <- predict(rf_reg, data = training_df)$predictions
```

Could anybody please explain why there is a discrepancy and what is causing it? Which one is correct? I have tried it with classification on `iris` data and that seemed to give the same results. Many thanks!

Comment: I am writing this as a comment because I'm going by memory / intuition, but I believe it's just an in-sample vs out-of-sample prediction difference. Even though the training_df is using for both. For instance, I would expect the first be something like a stacked prediction method and the second to be the final predictions. The docs probably describe it as well as any implicit partitioning settings.

Comment: Hard to guess without knowing what kind of data you gave it, and what kind of differences you got in results.  There is a always going to be at least a small difference between even identical runs because there is a lot of random sampling going on.

Answer (score 1):

The predictions using `rf_reg$predictions` are based only on the out-of-bag samples (as stated in the "value" section of `?ranger`). On the other hand, `predict.ranger` is based on all samples.

To demonstrate this, first lets train a RF model (using mtcars as some example data).  We use the `keep.inbag = TRUE` argument, so that we will know which samples were in-bag versus out-of-bag for each tree.

```
rf = ranger(formula = mpg ~ ., data = mtcars, keep.inbag = TRUE)
```

Now we generate the predictions using three methods.  The first two are the same as in the question.  We also add a third predict method where we specify `predict.all = TRUE`, which will give us separate predictions for all trees. That will allow us to take averages of the individual tree predictions according to whether the observation was in or out of bag.

```
results.rf   = rf$predictions   # based on out-of-bag samples
results.pred = predict(rf, data = mtcars)$predictions #  based on all samples
results.all  = predict(rf, data = mtcars, predict.all = TRUE)$predictions # has all trees and all samples
```

Now we can check

1. whether `results.pred` is identical to the average across all trees from `results.all`; and
2. whether `results.rf` is identical to the average across all trees from only the out-of-bag samples.

I demonstrate here for the first sample (i.e. the first row in mtcars).

```
inbag.counts = sapply(rf$inbag.counts, \(x) x[1])
oob = (inbag.counts == 0) # logical vector of which trees the sample is out-of-bag. 

all.equal(mean(results.all[1,    ]),  results.pred[1])
# [1] TRUE
all.equal(mean(results.all[1, oob]),  results.rf  [1])
# [1] TRUE
```

We can do the same check for all rows too:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(mtcars)) {
  inbag.counts = sapply(rf$inbag.counts, \(x) x[i])
  oob = (inbag.counts == 0) 
  print(all.equal(mean(results.all[i,    ]),  results.pred[i]))
  print(all.equal(mean(results.all[i, oob]),  results.rf  [i]))
}
```